# Insert Line in File When Group of Lines Changes

Tags: text-processing, sed, awk

Let's say I have a text file like this:

```
group1 hello
group1 there
group1 nice line
group2 here
group2 we
group2 go
```

What I want to do is insert a line when the group of lines changes, something like:

```
group1 hello
group1 there
group1 nice line
---------------------------------------
group2 here
group2 we
group2 go
```

I don't care if that line also appears as the first and/or last line. At this time I only need something that separates the information.

How do I do that with `sed` or `awk`? Or maybe there are other ways?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `awk`:

```
awk 'NR!=1&&x!=$1{print "---"} {x=$1}1' file
```

- `NR!=1&&x!=$1`: applies for all lines, except the first line and checks if the first field has changed.
- `print "---"`: if yes, print the dashes.
- `{x=$1}`: set x for the next iteration.
- `1`: a true condition that `awk` prints each line.

Comment: That was quick, thanks! And it works for me :)